# I'm having these issues with flutter_vlc_player, why is that?

Tags: flutter, streaming, vlc, ngrok

I'm testing a dependency of flutter and having these issues while trying to show video streaming using ngrok, these are the issues i have:

```
E/VLC     (15337): [00000071a614bc90/3c35] libvlc stream: HTTP connection failure
E/VLC     (15337): [00000071a614bc90/3c35] libvlc stream: connection failed: Network is unreachable
E/VLC     (15337): [00000071a614bc90/3c35] libvlc stream: cannot connect to ae872c2bd308.ngrok.io:80
```

and this is code I'm using:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  VlcPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _videoPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.network(
      'http://ae872c2bd308.ngrok.io/stream',
      hwAcc: HwAcc.FULL,
      autoPlay: false,
      options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    await _videoPlayerController.stopRendererScanning();
    await _videoPlayerController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: VlcPlayer(
          controller: _videoPlayerController,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea of what could be the problem?

I tested the transmission using VLC player and it is possible to make it work.

Comment: checked your internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

Add `autoPlay: true` to the controller so it becomes

```
_videoPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.network(
  'http://ae872c2bd308.ngrok.io/stream',
  hwAcc: HwAcc.FULL,
  autoPlay: true,
  options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
);
```